# Arm message invalid literal constant: pool needs to be closer

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, arm

Before i start i need to say that i have checked other question for which my question could be marked as duplicate and it didn't help me. The thing is i made for an assignment a program that recives an array and prints it out in reverse, when i compiled in ARMSim (rquired for the assignment) it showed me this error:
[image]

[image]

operands seems to be an array of 3 0's `operands: .word   0, 0, 0` that is in .data
The function prints itoa and atoi (that is above itoa) come from UsefulFunctions, a file in the #ARMSim official page.
If anynone could explain this error to me it would be much obliged.

Comment: Put a literal pool nearby.  I'm not sure what the exact directive for that is in the assembler you use. Also, please do not post pictures of code.  Always post code as text!

Comment: @fuz ok i'll have that in mind next time. But i don't understand what it refers to as "pool", what is that?

Comment: It's about *literal pools*, regions of memory next to your code where the assembly places constants for `ldr reg, =...` instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the  `LDR =` pseudo-instruction, it turns into a `PC`-relative load from what's called a "literal pool" (i.e. a pool of literals).

Normally these are placed automatically at the end of each code section. But sometimes that might be too far to be reachable by the load instruction, in which case you may need to emit some literal pools yourself, e.g. at the end of each function (after the last return instruction).

Depending on which assembler you use, the directive for emitting a literal pool might be `.pool`, `LTORG`, or something else.

Comment: Note that as said pool contains data, you should put it somewhere control flow will never reach (such as after an unconditional jump).